# null records being submitted on create action for new client record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, null, posts

I'm a complete noob at rails, but have been teaching myself and I seem to be able to resolve the simple issues myself. However I have a issue at the moment that I can't seem to resolve. When I call my 'new' or 'create' actions to create a new record after filling in all the fields on the form, I get blank records being committed to the database. all the fields are 'null'.

```
INSERT INTO `clients` (`accountholder`, `allergies`, `birthdate`, `cell`, `created_at`, `data1`, `data2`, `data3`, `data4`, `emailaddress`, `fax`, `middlename`, `name`, `surname`, `tel`, `text`, `updated_at`) VALUES (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '2012-08-20 09:10:46', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '2012-08-20 09:10:46')
```

I can see the data during log dump on console in the @post = Client.update_attributes(params[:id]) are correct.

clients_controller.rb

```
def new
  @post = Client.create
end

def create
  @post = Client.new(params[:posts])

   if @post.save
    redirect_to clients_path
   else
    render "new"
   end
end
```

index.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @post do |x| %>
    <p>
        <%= x.label :name %><br />
        <%= x.text_field :name, :cols => "30", :rows => "1" %>
    </p>

    <p>
        <%= x.label :surname %>
        <%= x.text_area :surname, :cols => "30", :rows => "1" %>
    </p>

    <p>
        <%= x.label :middlename %>
        <%= x.text_area :middlename, :cols => "30", :rows => "1" %>
    </p>

    <p>
        <%= x.label :tel %>
        <%= x.text_area :tel, :cols => "30", :rows => "1" %>
    </p>

    <p>
        <%= x.label :cell %>
        <%= x.text_area :cell, :cols => "30", :rows => "1" %>
    </p>

    <p>
        <%= x.label :allergies %>
        <%= x.text_area :allergies, :cols => "30", :rows => "10" %>
    </p>

    <p>
        <%= x.label :fax %>
        <%= x.text_area :fax, :cols => "30", :rows => "1" %>
    </p>

    <p>
        <%= x.label :birthdate %>
        <%= x.text_area :birthdate, :cols => "30", :rows => "1" %>
    </p>


    <p>
        <%= x.submit "Add a New Client" %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
@post = Client.new(params[:posts])
```

should be:

```
@post = Client.new(params[:client])
```

`params[:posts]` is not defined, therefore it is nil. That is like calling Client.new(), meaning attributes are NULL by default.

The class name is Client, and the client you are trying to create is singular, hence **client**. In Rails, normally a collection of clients are referred to as clients , and a client is client.

That's why by default, you see the the `index` action use `@clients` (because it's plural), and the `show` action uses `@client`.

Comment: thank you for the reply. I made the changes but still get null values.    

(0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO `clients` (`accountholder`, `allergies`, `birthdate`, `cell`, `created_at`, `data1`, `data2`, `data3`, `data4`, `emailaddress`, `fax`, `middlename`, `name`, `surname`, `tel`, `text`, `updated_at`) VALUES (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '2012-08-23 19:18:59', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '2012-08-23 19:18:59')
   (343.6ms)  COMMIT

Comment: but right before the SQL statement i get the values... ... Processing by ClientsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"commit"=>"Add a New Client", "authenticity_token"=>"PxoggVrFup3IJNH/+zILwI9KOVfOalhr2gElf7BFBAI=", "utf8"=>"✓", "client"=>{"middlename"=>"abraham", "cell"=>"7373737", "allergies"=>"jdjdjdjdjndjndjn", "surname"=>"nel", "tel"=>"737373737", "name"=>"wilhelm", "fax"=>"63782637", "birthdate"=>"01/01/2000"}}

Comment: ahh, based on your last comment, it's actually in params[:client]. I've changed my answer. forms_for must be using the name of the class of the object (`@post.class == Client`). It would probably be clearer if you changed your `@post` variables to `@client`.

Comment: just add a 'raise "testing"' at the beginning of the update/create action and checkout the rails debug output. There's a dump of the params hash (you can find the same thing in the log) which tells you what the correct name is.